# HTML dropdown menu doesn't work when I import bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am doing a project where I need bootstrap. It works perfectly but when I try to add a dropdown menu it isn't working. Also, I am making the dropdown menu from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown_navbar.asp). Here is html code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">  
<div class="menu">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

And here is the css code:

```
     .menu {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: transparent;
        font-family: Arial;
      }
      
      .menu a {
        float: left;
        font-size: 25px;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      
      .dropdown {
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      
      .dropdown .dropbtn {
        font-size: 25px;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 15px;
        background-color: inherit;
        font-family: inherit;
        margin: 0;
      }
      
      .menu a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        color:white;
        text-decoration:underline;
        text-decoration-color:white;
      }
      
      .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
      }
      
      .dropdown-content a {
        float: none;
        color: black;
        padding: 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
      }
      
      .dropdown-content a:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
      }
      
      .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
      }
```

When I delete the `<link rel="stylesheet"href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">`  the dropdown works perfectly but when I add it it doesn't work.

Please reply.

Comment: Did you try to add `Bootstrap.js` in your page?
From **Bootstrap** official site: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/#js

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this problem is clear! If you read [bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/dropdowns/) about dropdowns, you would notice that `dropdown` class is one of the classes that are used by bootstrap. So to solve the issue you need to change your class name to something else like `dropdownME` class, like the code below:

```css
.menu {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #000;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.menu a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdownME {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdownME .dropbtn {
    font-size: 25px;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

.menu a:hover, .dropdownME:hover .dropbtn {
    color:white;
    text-decoration:underline;
    text-decoration-color:white;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdownME:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="menu">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <div class="dropdownME">
        <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I also change the **background-color** of `.menu` for better showing.